# What does the colon in "ajax:success" mean in JavaScript when it wasn't written inside an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I saw this snippet on the Rails Guides:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#new_post").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    $("#new_post").append xhr.responseText
  ).bind "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
    $("#new_post").append "<p>ERROR</p>"
```

I know the syntax for object literals in JS, e.g. `{ a: b }` but I don't see any braces here. What's the colon mean? Is it the name of an event and there happens to be a colon in it?

Snippet from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html
, Section 3.1

Comment: Seems to be in CoffeeScript - `Rails ships with CoffeeScript by default, and so the rest of the examples in this guide will be in CoffeeScript.`

Comment: Anything between `"` or `'` is a **string** and usually doesn't have any specific meaning in JavaScript (aside from "use strict";`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `"ajax:success"` is just a string that jQuery decided to use as the name to correspond with the completion of an AJAX request.

It really has nothing to do with the object literals at all; it is just text.  The only reason they decided to use the colon is to make it clear that it is the AJAX object that is succeeding.  jQuery could have chosen any other name (ex: `.on("ajax_success",`, `.on("ajaxwassuccessful",`, etc.) if they wanted to.

It is not an object literal, not JSON, just a simple old string.